# WIX Change category of blog posts when in a repeater via a button using Velo code

Tags: velo

So, I've been told to design a wix blog age that displays posts in a repeater and be able to change the category of those listed posts via buttons. Why a repeater? Because one can't design the blog post list as freely as a repeater.

I've included a snippet of the section in question. There are 5 categories all of which are to show 3 posts per category.

I've not been able to figure out a code that works to switch the category of the posts... when I try, I get a:

1. "error: WDE 0080: Validation failed"
2. Nothing happens
3. the entire repeater disappears with no error in the console.

Any help?

[image]

NOTE: I unlinked the image and title for privacy reasons. ALSO you see the "Articles" category written on the 1st post, that's because it is under both Featured and Articles categories NOTE: I unlinked the image and title for privacy reasons. ALSO you see the "Articles" category written on the 1st post, that's because it is under both Featured and Articles categories

I even tried to use ChatGPT as a saw no similar situations when googled.